# Looking for a way to filter the result of these UNION queries in SQL

Tags: sql, filter, union

I would like to filter the result of these 2 queries, connected by UNION. I think of adding a SELECT statement to filter the latest in terms of date, ID and name. The issue is that these 2 queries produce a duplicate after using UNION, which I have to avoid. Only need one latest date, name and ID.

```
(select  authorize_id,
purchase_authorizer_api.Get_Name(authorize_id) as "Authorizer Name",  
max(date_approved) as "Last Date Approved", 'PR' as "Approval Type"
from PURCH_REQ_LINE_APPROVAL
group by authorize_id )

union 

( select  authorize_id,
purchase_authorizer_api.get_name(authorize_id) as "Authorizer Name",
 max(date_approved) as "Last Date Approved", 'PO' as "Approval Type"
from PURCHASE_ORDER_APPROVAL
group by authorize_id )
```

Here is some sample data from the 2 queries:

```
AUTHORIZE_ID    Authorizer Name     Last Date Approved  Approval Type
AANDR           Alfredo And         2012-10-16 12:51           PR
AANDR           Alfredo And         2016-09-06 13:08           PO
AESFAH          Arash Esf           2017-05-26 13:28           PO
AHAMM           Ahmed Hamd          2019-12-04 14:15           PO
AJAHAN          Al Jaha             2012-11-02 9:56            PR
AJAHAN          Al Jaha             2013-10-29 14:17           PO
```

I would like to get only the latest date from these, so it will avoid duplicates.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: strictly speaking, the result of `UNION` cannot contain duplicates.  You would need `UNION ALL` in order to prevent it from filtering out duplicate results.  Presumably your definition of "duplicate" only includes certain columns

Comment: UNION will not produce duplicates, UNION ALL will.  Look at the output data.  I'll bet the two rows don't really match.  But I don't think that's the problem.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: UNION won't give duplicates. Field Approval Type is different between the two selects so no way to generate dupplicates caused by the UNION. Can you provide an example with data pls?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function on the `UNION` of the 2 tables to return 1 row for each `authorize_id`:

```
with cte as (
  select authorize_id, date_approved, 'PR' as "Approval Type" from PURCH_REQ_LINE_APPROVAL  
  union all
  select authorize_id, date_approved, 'PO' as "Approval Type" from PURCHASE_ORDER_APPROVAL 
)
select 
  t.authorize_id, 
  purchase_authorizer_api.Get_Name(t.authorize_id) as "Authorizer Name", 
  t.date_approved as "Last Date Approved", 
  t."Approval Type" 
from (
  select c.*, row_number() over (partition by c.authorize_id order by c.date_approved desc) rn
  from cte c
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ik4HwrtFVGdN1rz3Bez7mm/1) (without `Authorizer Name`).
Results:

```
| authorize_id | Authorizer Name | Last Date Approved       | Approval Type |
| ------------ | --------------- | ------------------------ | ------------- |
| AANDR        |                 | 2016-09-06T13:08:00.000Z | PO            |
| AESFAH       |                 | 2017-05-26T13:28:00.000Z | PO            |
| AHAMM        |                 | 2019-12-04T14:15:00.000Z | PO            |
| AJAHAN       |                 | 2013-10-29T14:17:00.000Z | PO            |
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. Unfortunately it's giving me an error on line 12 ('' select *, row_number....) says FROM keyword not found where expected. I am using PL/SQL.

Comment: That one worked. I noticed what the issue was. Thanks again!